# Can you explain how scanner works? Does it print everything?

Tags: java

I was trying to understand how scanner worked. So, I tied to scan in a text document and iterate only through certain words but it didn't work, it just printed everything. So, I replaced it with a loop that just printed numbers but it never even printed it and it printed all the words in the text document even though I didn't write a print statement for that. **Does scanner just automatically print everything? How come my for loop is being skipped too?**

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
read.close();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: *Does scanner just automatically print everything?* - No, and the behaviour you describe is actually impossible. Please, share all your attempts (even the one that *printed without you writing a print statement for that*).

Comment: this is literally all I wrote. I ran it and then it printed every word on a new line

Comment: What you wrote _cannot_ have printed the contents of the file. The only thing that's printed are the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. If you're seeing something else then provide a [mcve].

Comment: You didn't recompile after changing the code; your posted code does not read anything from the file.

Comment: Have you tried to google some examples?

Comment: `Scanner` doesn't print anything: your code does, but not what you claimed. Clearly this isn't the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code to this :

Generic Code :

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
while (reader.hasNext()){
   String str = reader.nextLine();
   System.out.println(str);
}

reader.close();
```

For reading integers :

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
while (reader.hasNext()){
  int i = reader.nextInt();
  System.out.println(i);
}

reader.close();
```

> When Scanner is used with a text file, it behaves a bit like an
>   iterator with collections. The method hasNext detects the end of the
>   file, so a simple while loop can be used to read through a file of
>   data.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` is not such a nice class, as in reading one has to determine what kind of token one wants to read, and preferably handle all errors.

It reads sequentially a file as tokens, separated default by spaces, and a token can be `String/int/...`.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
if (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
}
if (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int n = in.nextInt();
    if (in.hasNext()) {
        String s = in.next();
    }
    if (in.hasNextLine()) {
        in.nextLine();
    }
}
int a = in.nextInt(); // Unsafe - are there digits here?
int b = in.nextInt();
in.close();
```

For a file:

```
My header line
42 fine secret
97 98
```

One can easily make a mistake.